# Using AWS, is there a way to build an AMI so it auto-joins the domain?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, domain, amazon-ami

So we want to let developers have access into AWS natively, and when building a windows machine have it automatically join the domain and potentially add some tools, etc. Since I am used to using the native Amazon AMIs without domain infrastructure, what is the best way to go about doing this?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Using_WinAMI.html

Comment: Doesn't give a lot of guidance around domain joins.

Comment: So you want to know how to automatically join a domain? Or run sysprep? Or....what?

Comment: "I am used to using the native Amazon AMIs without domain infrastructure" You can't join a non-existent domain... I think you need to clarify your question with exactly what you want to do. If you have DNS resolution working properly there is nothing unusual about the AWS AMIs

Comment: We have a domain built out, my question is more on launching a new server, that it autojoins the domain.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon have recently made this an easier process via the new  [Amazon Directory Service](http://aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/). You can run a stand alone AD domain "Simple AD" or extend an existing AS to AWS via the "AD Connector"

Essentially Amazon provides something called "SSM" or [Simple Systems Manager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-configuration-manage.html) that helps you manage Windows instances. One of those facilities is "Domain Join". 
Once you have your sample AD setup, you can use the Domain Join facility described below [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-join-aws-domain.html).  Basically you create an "SSM" document with your AD details and associate this document with your instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have used in the past - just make sure you have the domain infrastructure in place:

```
$UserData = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String(
    [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(@‘
<powershell>
Get-NetFirewallRule | Where { $_.DisplayName -eq “Windows Management Instrumentation (ASync-In)” } |               Enable-NetFirewallRule

Get-NetFirewallRule | Where { $_.DisplayName -eq “Windows Management Instrumentation (DCOM-In)” } |      Enable-NetFirewallRule

Get-NetFirewallRule | Where { $_.DisplayName -eq “Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI-In)” } |    Enable-NetFirewallRule
</powershell>
‘@))

$Reservation = New-EC2Instance - ImageId $AMI -KeyName $KeyName -SubnetId $SubnetId -InstanceType        $InstanceType -MinCount 1 -MaxCount 1 -UserData $UserData

$Instance = $Reservation.RunningInstance[0].InstanceId
$IP = $Reservation.RunningInstance[0].PrivateIpAddress

$Tag = New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.Tag
$Tag.Key = ‘Name’
$Tag.Value = $ServerName
New-EC2Tag -ResourceId $Instance -Tag $Tag

$LocalPassword = $null
While( $LocalPassword -eq $null) {
Try {
  Write-Host “Waiting for Password.”
   $LocalPassword = Get-EC2PasswordData -InstanceId $InstanceId
        -PemFile $PemFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
]Catch{}
Start-Sleep -s 60

$DomainPassword = $DomainPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$DomainCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential(“administrator”,    $LocalPassword)

Add-Computer -ComputerName $LocalComputer -LocalCredential $LocalCredential
 -NewName $ServerName -DomainName $DomainName
 -Credential $DomainCredential -Restart -Force
```